# Windows 7 Features Not Found In Previous Versions

Tags: windows-7, windows

What are some things you can in Windows 7 that you couldn't do in previous versions of Windows? Don't limit your answers to a single feature, I want to learn as much as possible.

Comment: Why does this question have an accepted answer? Was that what you wanted?

Comment: @Troggy: No this isn't what I wanted, no offense to JP. I set up a bounty to get more attention, which requires an accepted answer. Personally I think jay's answer should be the accepted one, but it wasn't posted during the bounty and now I can't change it.

Comment: That is ok, it was an older question, so I was just checking up on it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: **Please double-check before voting to close as *not constructive*. It involves facts!**

Comment: I know the comments I'm replying to are almost two years old, but: Now that the bounty system has been revamped, I believe you can un-accept the answer, and that doing so won't screw up the bounty.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Some other great additions:*

**Math input panel** quite simply because it can read my handwriting better than humans.

[image]

**Better Calculator** with history of recent calculations and a myriad of new advanced functions for statistics and programming. Also worksheets for day-to-day calculations such as fuel economy, date calculations, unit conversions.

[image]

**Ribbon Interface** in the old accessories such as WordPad, Paint etc. These incorporate the new UI introduced by Office 07 and hide a few new additional features.

**Whole screen Magnifier** Pressing `Windows + (Plus)` magnifies the entire screen. (Awesome if you want to monitor downloads from a far). Also has other view options.

**Libraries** are a new folder system which contain folders from various locations. For example Music library can contain folders from e:\music, c:\users\me\music, d:\downloads\music, and deal with all the files together.

**Homegroups** vastly simplifies sharing files on a home network.

**Searching** is looks way more cleaner with highlights and the new 'Content' view.

[image: content view]

**Federated Search** allows for custom search providers (in example below YouTube) from Explorer. This is especially useful for desktop programs which have searchable content like OneNote, Stickies etc.

[image: searching youtube via explorer]

*However* by far the best feature would have to be XP Mode!

**XP Mode** allows you to install and run programs in a virtual machine running XP. This is awesome if you have programs that only work on XP. What's more it allows for seamless integration as you can see below, XP's IE6 running besides Firefox on 7 on the same machine.

[image: XP Mode demo]

Comment: +1 for taking each snapshot with a different wallpaper/theme :)

Answer (score 30):

Rearrange taskbar buttons.

Comment: and pin them, so they stay there even when the application is closed.

Comment: This is a great out-of-the-box feature for windows 7, would always have to install 3rd party tools on previous versions.

Answer (score 25):

Drag window against the left or right edge to fill half the screen, top edge to maximize.

Grab a maximized titlebar and pull to restore.

Shake the titlebar to minimize everybody else.

Comment: I did not know that you could shake.

Comment: You can also for some reason resize a window to the top/bottom of the screen to fill the height.

Comment: Great on a touchscreen. On the other hand, with the keyboard, Win+up, Win+down, Win+left, Win+right do fill half the screen, maximize, restore, minize.

Answer (score 15):

Some of mine and some from [7 Reasons to Upgrade to Windows 7](http://www.redmondpie.com/7-reasons-to-upgrade-to-windows-7/):

- Faster startup and shutdown times (Technically not a new feature, but very nice still)
- Windows 7 Libraries (I really like these ones myself).
- Desktop enhancements like Aero Peek, Aero Shake, a nice Wallpaper slideshow feature and gadgets no longer being restricted to a gadget bar.
- The new and brilliant taskbar with jump lists and previews. Also lets you pin programs so it is like a combined quick launch bar and task bar.
- A home group feature which makes it super simple to share files in your home network (seriously, I was surprised how easy it actually was to set up!)
- Better battery utilization.
- Support for touch and multi-touch.
- Much easier to connect to wlan hot spots.
- A very handy Resource Monitor

Comment: that taskbar STILL does not span multiple monitors.  What an epic wall of FAIL!!!

Comment: Looking forward to HomeGroup.

Comment: HomeGroup is brilliant :D

Comment: Libraries rock - organizational brilliance.

Comment: @NoCarrier try UltraMon http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/smart_taskbar.asp

Comment: @NoCarrier: I agree, but I really wouldn't call that an "epic wall of FAIL" though. The improved task bar is still a whole bunch more awesome than it was in previous versions of Windows. Even without spanning multiple monitors.

Answer (score 12):

There are a whole bunch of cool new [keyboard shortcuts](http://lifehacker.com/5132073/the-best-new-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts).  (Not sure if that counts as mind blowing tho =)  And I love the [magnifier](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-use-windows-7-screen-magnifier/) -- use that constantly.

Comment: The magnifier seems similar to WinXP's magnifier: http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/magnifierturnon.aspx Not sure if it's a new feature.

Comment: It's much different actually, you should try it out.

Comment: @tpo: Try it with Aero enabled. Otherwise it will revert back to previous behavior.

Answer (score 10):

My favorite:  Burn an ISO CD/DVD.

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia has a fairly comprehensive list of [new features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7) in Windows 7.  I like that it has a lot more video codecs built in so I can watch my collection of video files without having to install anything extra.  Jump lists are pretty useful as well.

Answer (score 5):

The rearranging taskbar buttons is nice, I only recently learn you can do the same thing with tray icons!  No more going into the stupid customize dialog to get show/hide a tray icon.

Answer (score 5):

The ability to mount and create VHD natively using the Disk Manager. Also the ability to boot of a VHD.

*VHD = Virtual Hard Disk created by either Virtual PC or Hyper-V*

Answer (score 2):

You can play a game of Solitaire, leave it mid-game, close the program, then open it back up in the same state. I haven't tried it with the other games, but I think that is a cool feature.

Comment: Solitaire is Windows's killer app as well..

Comment: This was introduced by Vista.  I don't think the games have changed at all in Windows 7 (AFAIK).

Comment: @Slaks, they removed Inkball from W7, my favorite, dirty rats. I tried to copy is from Vista, but it won't run, dirty rats again....http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InkBall

Comment: Ohhhhh, a workaround to make it run, oh joy!...http://thetechcorner.net/2009/01/11/inkball-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bit more support for touch interfaces.

For example, clicking a taskbar icon and dragging upward will bring up that icon's context menu/jump list (the same as right clicking). Similarly, clicking on IE's address bar and dragging downward will open up your history. Dragging to open a context menu makes sense because in a "touch only" scenario you wouldn't have the equivalent of a right-click.

I haven't confirmed that this "drag to open" feature affects all ComboBoxes but it wouldn't surprise me if it does.

Answer (score 2):

Much more versatile animated boot screen :)
[How do I change the Windows 7 boot animation?](https://superuser.com/questions/69050/how-to-change-the-windows-7-boot-screen/234944)
Finally!

Answer (score 1):

[Snap feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/03/17/designing-aero-snap.aspx)