# Any compelling reasons for upgrading Vista to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

I have been using Windows Vista since it first came out and had no problems so far.

Are there any compelling reason to upgrade Windows Vista to Windows 7?

It seems like windows 7 is slightly faster but I don't know if coughing up $150~$200 can be justified.

(not a real question: By the way, has anyone ever downgraded Win7 to Vista or XP?)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/4287/windows-7-features-not-found-in-previous-versions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been running Windows 7 at home now since the beta and have been loving it.  I definitely think its an improvement in speed, reliability, ease of use and overall productivity over Vista and especially XP (used Vista for about a year before 7, and XP still at work).  At work I find myself missing many features on my XP machine that I use often at home.  What are some of these features?  Check out these topics:

- [What can be done in Windows 7 that can’t be done in Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/14147/what-can-be-done-in-windows-7-that-cant-be-done-in-windows-xp)
- [Windows 7 tips and tricks](https://superuser.com/questions/7622/windows-7-tips-and-tricks)
- [Windows 7 Features Not Found In Previous Versions](https://superuser.com/questions/4287/windows-7-features-not-found-in-previous-versions)

Comment: +1 - Windows 7 is a massive upgrade over Windows 7. More features, easier to use, less harassment from the UAC and operating system in general, it's very nice to look at. Oh, and did we mention faster, more stable?

Answer (score 6):

It's supposed to be a great service pack, see [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001290.html).

Answer (score 5):

Compelling reason?  That depends on you I suppose.  I didn't have a great experience with Vista, so I stuck with XP and Server 2008 as my primary environments.  But, I have really enjoyed Windows 7 to the point where I feel comfortable leaving XP behind.  Meanwhile, check out [Features new to Windows 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7) and see if, for you, any of those is compelling. :)

Answer (score 1):

If there's a new upgrade for $50 sale, then it's absolutely worth the trouble, if only for the reduced load Windows 7 has on your computer.

Comment: Argh.  Missed the promotional price.

Comment: Use the RC, wait untill there's a new promotion, get it then ;-)

Comment: Ha, just found out about family pack...  It seems like that's what I need to install 3 of my machines.!