# Should I upgrade Windows Vista to Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any compelling reasons for upgrading Vista to Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/19393/any-compelling-reasons-for-upgrading-vista-to-windows-7)

I purchased an HP laptop from the Costco about 1 month ago, and they offered free upgrading to Windows 7 when it's available. So, should I upgrade my system to Windows 7 or just run with Vista 64 - please help me understand. Many thanks

Comment: Should be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: This is a little too similar to http://superuser.com/questions/19393/any-compelling-reasons-for-upgrading-vista-to-windows-7

Answer (score 7):

Migrate to Windows 7. There are no good reasons for staying on Vista unless you have some weird software that you absolutely must use but which doesn't run on Windows 7.

Comment: +1 because Win7 is what Vista should have been (I never liked Vista). Fix a mistake and upgrade. 7 has better performance (subjective) and it _works_ better, there are fewer annoying things in how you operate it.

Answer (score 5):

There are heaps of problems you can get into, such as having Win7 installed while the HP restore partition still contains Vista. Better check this problem with HP support and don't migrate without a solution.

Here is the list of [Windows 7 features](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features). See if there's anything in there that you can't live without.
If you aren't very keen on any of them, better follow the rule of "If it ain't broken, don't fix it". You can always upgrade to Win7 later (if HP have supplied you with the CD).

Comment: I upgraded my wife's older Sony Vista laptop without issue.  All done while the Sony restore partition was present.  YMMV

Comment: Yes, but what I meant was: if you ever find yourself with a dead or infected Windows 7 and decide to restore from the HP partition, you would find that Vista was re-installed, and so you'll need to redo the upgrade to Win7.

Answer (score 0):

My attitude would be why *not* upgrade if it's free (or close to it)? Especially as it's a fairly new laptop (with little to backup and move across).

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded and noticed huge improvements in printer driver support, and have come to love the interface improvements (desktop preview, jump lists, and some of the funny mouse gestures like shaking windows).  Overall, it blows vista away IMO, and if you get it free, no reason not to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are significant improvements in performance, and useful improvements in the user interface as well.  The taskbar now does many of the same things as the Mac OS X dock once you pin applications to it, and you can move or shake an app's title bar to maximize/minimize/tile a window or to minimize all other windows.  7 basucally is Vusta so there should be very few compatibility issues, far fewer than when migrating from XP to Vista.