# How do I change the Windows 7 boot animation?

Tags: windows-7

I want to change Windows 7's boot screen. Is there any way?

Note that I'm not referring to the logon screen; I'm talking about the screen which you see **before** the welcome screen:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit alex. Indeed this was getting out of hand.

Comment: No problem. It hurts my eyes to see things all over the place.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is what you're after:
http://www.coderforlife.com/projects/win7boot/

If you want some examples of what you can do, these are some of the better replacement animations readily available:

[image] [image] [image]

[image] [image]

http://zangio.deviantart.com/art/Win7-Boot-Animation-STARGATE-189992814

http://die77.deviantart.com/art/Laptop-ed-win7-bootscreen-188894205

http://zangio.deviantart.com/art/Win7-Boot-Animation-7spiral-189458286?q=sort%3Atime+gallery%3Azangio&qo=4

http://zangio.deviantart.com/art/Win7-Boot-Animation-ACDC-190250214

http://zangio.deviantart.com/art/Win7-Boot-Animation-sliding-7-188125276

http://fnxrak.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-BootScreen-193989599?q=in%3Acustomization%2Fskins%2Fwindows7%20sort%3Atime%20boot&qo=0

http://ozzy8031.deviantart.com/art/Glow-Windows7-Boot-Replacement-186155298?q=boost%3Apopular%20in%3Acustomization%2Fskins%2Fwindows7%20boot&qo=1

If you want to make your own the program is pretty flexible but the one main requirement is making sure your animation contains 105 frames. You can of course use duplicates if you can't come up with that many unique frames of animation.

Comment: Thank you, I would suggest the second link for laptop users, it's great. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only tool I know so far that can do it is [TuneUp Utilities 2010](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Change_Windows_7_Boot_Screen_26501148) (which btw, is also a nice tool to keep your Windows 7 stable and cleaned).

It's possible that other tools will start to emerge. However the **official Microsoft position** [was stated long ago](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/e7/engineering-the-windows-7-boot-animation) (bottom of the page). So any solution will only be presented in the shape of third-party tools and most likely Microsoft will never provide a direct way for you to do it.

Comment: BTW: TuneUp was just updated to TuneUp Utilities 2010. I'm currently running the 30 day trial.

Comment: It was actually a typo. Thanks for the reminder. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  Windows allows OEMs to change the login wallpaper and it is easily done with a registry hack and placement of the correct files.  see [Change Windows 7 Logon Screen](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-windows-7-logon-screen-easily-without-using-hacks-tools/)

Summary:

Create registry key:  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background]
"OEMBackground"=dword:00000001`

Place image files in `C:\Windows\System32\oobe\Info\Backgrounds` that are the correct size:

```
* backgroundDefault.jpg
* background768×1280.jpg 
* background900×1440.jpg 
* background960×1280.jpg 
* background1024×1280.jpg 
* background1280×1024.jpg
* background1024×768.jpg  
* background1280×960.jpg
* background1600×1200.jpg 
* background1440×900.jpg
* background1920×1200.jpg 
* background1280×768.jpg 
* background1360×768.jpg
```

Note:  the files must be <= 256KB

Comment: I think u talk about changing logon screen where user enter his password . But he talk about the screen before screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I found out. Go to "C:\Windows\System32\en-US" and find the file "winload.exe.mui". If you can find another boot screen that you like, I assume that you can just name it "winload.exe.mui" and replace the original one. I believe this will work, but I recommend making a backup of your computer before trying this.

Disclaimer:
I am in no way responsible if this directly or indirectly ruins, crashes, or messes up your computer, or if you lose or make corrupt any files while trying this operation. If you do not agree with this then do not try this. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

(This would just be a comment on nathanchere's answer but I lack reputation points)

Hello from 2023! The link in nathanchere's answer was blocked by Malwarebytes due to the apparent distribution of a Trojan, however, [the Internet Archive's snapshot of the page from 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120717082916/http://www.coderforlife.com/projects/win7boot/) appears to be a safe way to get the original software referred to in that answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1178963)