# application that can customize windows 7 boot screen

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

how do customize windows 7 boot screen.
Found this one: [How do I change the Windows 7 boot animation?](https://superuser.com/questions/69050/how-to-change-the-windows-7-boot-screen)
But what I want to find out if there is an application that can do this. Except for TU 2010.
A tutorial that can help me make a custom boot screen will also help. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the Windows 7 Boot Screen](http://superuser.com/questions/69050/how-to-change-the-windows-7-boot-screen)

Comment: I'm asking for a tool that can create custom boot screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [this](http://www.blogsdna.com/5932/change-windows-7-vista-xp-boot-animation-with-boot-bmp-changer.htm) thingy.
Else, TuneUp is pretty much your only graphical option.