# How can I make the Windows boot process look more like that of Knoppix?

Tags: windows

I wish to have my computer say initiating startup services with some cool animation and initiating shut down sequences much like knoppix ? How this can be done?

Comment: 1. Hack Windows and replace boot text/animation. 2. Create your own apps and set them to run on startup and shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

As for the "cool animation", check out the answers this other SuperUser question.

[How do I change the Windows 7 boot animation?](https://superuser.com/questions/69050/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-boot-animation)

As for the "initiating shutdown sequence", you can get the sounds from the following page, and then just set them to the appropriate event in Control Panel -> Sounds:

http://barnettcomputerrepair.com/computers/knoppix-startup-and-shutdown-sounds/