# Minidump folder cannot be found

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod, minidumps

Although I have enabled the creation of minidump files in my system, it appears that either Windows doesn't create them where the Startup and recovery dialog points to (%SystemRoot%\Minidump) or at least I can't find them.

Even the Minidump folder under Windows directory is missing and I had numerous BSODs till now. I've searched all my HDs for mini*.dmp files only to find some old ones in a backup folder from my Vista 32-bit installation, before I install Windows 7 64-bit.

Any thoughts of why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Is there a way to test creation of a minidump? I don't exaclty know how to cause a blue screen safely...

Comment: sure is.  i used to have a utility called `crash.exe` (or maybe it was `crash3.exe`, it's been a while).  used it for inducing system crashes (and thus dump creation) for testing XP driver code.  no idea where it came from, tho.  not sure how "safe" it was, but these were test systems and could always be reloaded.

Comment: i was wrong on the name; it was OSR's bang.exe utility: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=153 .. download and run, pops up a big red button that reads "Crash Now!", just press when ready.  also allows you to cancel if necessary.

Comment: @quack: Can I find this or similar program, without generating account to a site?

Comment: no idea.  i went ahead and registered to grab the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running without a swap file? Apparently, [you need a paging file of at least 2MB on the boot volume for a minidump](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263).

Comment: I have it this way, should I change it?  
http://www.screencast.com/t/YjdjZmVkNz

Comment: No, that looks OK. The system-managed settings have chosen about 4GB for the page file on the C: drive. The cause must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in control panel/ troubleshooting then view history or view all and see the list of programs, hardware or other problems that have occurred and then choose a file and click view details. This will give you better detail then just your Minidump file will.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately history is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the event logs?  There should be an entry for any BSODs and minidump creations in the System events.

> **[Edit: Checking event logs]**
>   In the event viewer, you're looking for Information
>   entries from *Save Dump*.  Open *View -> Filter* and select
>   *Save Dump* in the *source* drop-down list.  (You could also filter on EventID *1001*.) Hit *OK*.
>
> This should leave you with a list of entries sent by the "Save Dump" process
>   during a post-BSOD bootup.  Double-click to show the full entry -- the 
>   description gives the location of the saved dump.
>
> - If there are entries but the files don't exist, your dumps are gone.
>     Maybe they were deleted by a system cleaner tool (CCleaner or the like).
> - If there aren't any entries, no dumps were saved.
>
> Make sure you've checked *"Write an event to the system log"* and
>   selected *"Small memory dump"* in the *Startup and Recovery* dialog.
>   You can also change the save location to whatever you like (eg, *"C:\dumps"*).

---

**Original:** I'd try using [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html); it may find existing minidumps automatically.  If they don't exist it'll be helpful once you get them going again.  Freeware, works under 32- and 64-bit Windows XP/Vista/7/etc.

[image]

Comment: BlueSceenView is the reason I am asking this question in the first place, it can't find anything, although I think that I've checked more thoroughly than it. About event logs, I will check them the next time system will crash.

Comment: unless you've *cleared* the event logs since earlier crashes, they should still retain the messages.

Comment: I haven't, but I don't remember when last blue screen happened and I don't know for what to look within my 55k system log entries...

Comment: EDIT: Either I don't have any events from Save dump / EventID 1001 or I am doing it wrong...

Comment: did you check the *startup and recovery* settings to make sure they're enabled?  (My Computer -> right click -> properties -> advanced -> "startup and recovery" settings)

Comment: Yes, it's the first thing I checked, as you can figure out from the first paragraph of my original question.

Comment: i figured you did, just double checking.

Comment: Nah, you did well. Now I guess the only thing is left is to find time to register, get bang.exe and cause BSOD. I can't say that I am in hurry for that :P