# How to become a superuser on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Features Not Found In Previous Versions](https://superuser.com/questions/4287/windows-7-features-not-found-in-previous-versions)

I'm a programmer. So it's a little embarrasing to admit it, but there a quite a few things under the hood of Windows 7 that I wish I knew. I'm not sure how my admin account seems to not have complete control on my corporate Win7 laptop. What are some good sources of information to get a technical person up to speed on the security, file system, etc. of Win7?

Comment: I fail to see how this question is duplicate of a question that asks "What are some things you can in Windows 7 that you couldn't do in previous versions of Windows? Don't limit your answers to a single feature, I want to learn as much as possible."

Comment: I agree. The features Blanthor asks for don't necessarily have to be present only on Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I've not watched much of it, but this talk looks good:

- http://www.securitytube.net/Windows-7-Security-Talk-by-Jorge-Orchilles-video.aspx

Comment: This is great information but I want to know more than just the securtiy model.

Answer (score 0):

You might do some reading over here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+7+elevated

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the hidden "real" Admin account in Windows 7, you can use this account when you are tired of fighting issues with the locked down user account.

Open an elevated command prompt, right click on the cmd icon and select run as administrator.

Type in:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Close the command prompt.

Log off, now you will see the new admin account to log into.

I don't recommend using this account for everyday use, I have done it, but don't recommend it to others.

When in the Admin account, two security aspects that are different than the user account

1. UAC is completely disabled
2. IE8 will not run in protected mode (sandbox)

Comment: "There simply is no easy way around all windows security." Running as the `system` account is a good start. I remember a hack where `narrator.exe` was replaced with `cmd.exe` and narrator was enabled in lock screen accessibility options, loading a command prompt running as system. Another way was running `cmd.exe` as a scheduled task.

Comment: **Remark by an anonymous editor:** Unfortunately, this will not result in the same level of power as Unix su.  For example, the user may still encounter problems updating the registry because of insufficient authority.  There simply is no easy way around *all* windows security.

Comment: Also, especially on a corporate laptop, it may very well be set up as a local administrator but may have other security restrictions and policies imposed on it by the group policies as part of the domain (active directory) that it is a part of.